# Traditional Food Mills as a Grain Mill / Dough to Blow @ W-S

Tags: mill, grain

Anyone have any experience with trying to use a traditional food mill to crush grain?  I'm afraid that I won't be able to get as fine of a crush as I need, plus it might be a pain in the neck to mill 10-15 lbs in such a small, non-motorized mill.

Long and short, my wife and I have some $ to spend @ Williams-Sonoma, and was looking for good things to buy that can assist in the 'brewing' element of our cooking life!

This is the one I was looking at:
http://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/all-clad-food-mill/?pkey=cspecialized-kitchen-tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know I will never hand-crank a mill again :)  That said, the type of mill you linked would not be useful for crushing grain.  That's a food mill, which is used to squish soft foods through a steel grate.

[image]

It would be good for crushing fruits for adding to beer, but not for crushing grain.  If that's what you're looking for, you want a [grain mill](http://www.midwestsupplies.com/all-grain-brewing/all-grain-equipment/grain-mills.html), which has heavy plates or rollers to crack the grain and release the endosperm from the husk.

Many brewers (myself included) started with a hand-cranked [Corona or Victoria](http://www.midwestsupplies.com/all-grain-brewing/all-grain-equipment/grain-mills/victoria-mill-with-high-hopper.html) grain mill.

[image]

While that can be motorized (sort of), most of us end up with a motorized roller mill, like the [MonsterMill MM-2](http://www.monsterbrewinghardware.com/mm-2.html) I use.

[image]

As for Williams-Sonoma, how about a big stainless spoon?  Maybe a stainless colander or two?  Some containers for storing grain/hops?